# Expose animation plays forward but not backward

Tags: gnome, animations

When I pres the superkey to trigger expose, the windows animate into place. However, when I hit the superkey again to leave expose, the windows just glitch back into their original position. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image: A gif of the animation in question]